# spring batch job should wait for prometheus to scrape before shutdown

Tags: spring-batch, prometheus

We have spring batch jobs running with **prometheus** as our monitoring system.
When the job is running metrics are being collected just fine, but when the job finish it **shutdowns before prometheus manage to collect the metric of "spring.batch.job"** which is crucial because it has 'duration' and 'status' tag which indicate wether the job succeeded or failed.

How can I program the job to wait for 'one last scrape' after its done before its shutdown?

Comment: Consider pushing metrics instead of pulling in case of temporary instances: https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/

Answer (score 0):

You can define what action you can do before shutdown using the configuration param in your application.yml

management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.shutdown-operation

and possible options are listed in org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusPushGatewayManager$ShutdownOperation